# React native Apple login stuck in enter password screen in IOS?

Tags: ios, react-native, sign-in-with-apple, apple-login

In IOS after entering the password it shows loading and nothing happens after that.There are no console logs?It's working fine in android.

I have implemented V2 of react native apple authentication
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-apple-authentication

[image]
Tried 2 codes below same issue.

Code 1

```
  const IOSAppleLogin = async () => {
        try {
            // performs login request
            const appleAuthRequestResponse = await appleAuth.performRequest({
                requestedOperation: appleAuth.Operation.LOGIN,
                requestedScopes: [appleAuth.Scope.EMAIL, appleAuth.Scope.FULL_NAME]
            });
    
            const credentialState = await appleAuth.getCredentialStateForUser(
                appleAuthRequestResponse.user
            );
    

            if (credentialState === appleAuth.State.AUTHORIZED) {

            console.log('appleAuthRequestResponse', appleAuthRequestResponse);
           
            const response = appleAuthRequestResponse;
            console.log('apple-response', response);
            // you may also want to send the device's ID to your server to link a device with the account
            // identityToken generated


            if (response) {
                if (response.identityToken) {
                    let device_identifier = DeviceInfo.getUniqueId();
                    let details = {
                        'identity_token': response.identityToken,
                        'first_name': response.fullName ? response.fullName.givenName : '-',
                        'last_name': response.fullName ? response.fullName.familyName : '-',
                        'device_identifier': device_identifier,
                        device: Platform.OS
                    };
                    props.appleLogin({ values: details });
                }
            }
            // user is authenticated
            }

        } catch (error) {
            if (appleAuth.Error.CANCELED === error.code) {
                console.log('apple-error-CANCELED', JSON.stringify(error));
            } else if (appleAuth.Error.FAILED === error.code) {
                console.log('apple-error-FAILED', error);
            } else if (appleAuth.Error.NOT_HANDLED === error.code) {
                console.log('apple-error-NOT_HANDLED', error);
            } else {
                console.log('apple-error', error);
            }
        }
    }
```

Code 2

```
  const IOSAppleLogin = async () => {
        try {
            // performs login request
            const appleAuthRequestResponse = await appleAuth.performRequest({
                requestedOperation: appleAuth.Operation.LOGIN,
                requestedScopes: [appleAuth.Scope.EMAIL, appleAuth.Scope.FULL_NAME]
            });
    

            console.log('appleAuthRequestResponse', appleAuthRequestResponse);
           
            const response = appleAuthRequestResponse;
            console.log('apple-response', response);
            // you may also want to send the device's ID to your server to link a device with the account
            // identityToken generated


            if (response) {
                if (response.identityToken) {
                    let device_identifier = DeviceInfo.getUniqueId();
                    let details = {
                        'identity_token': response.identityToken,
                        'first_name': response.fullName ? response.fullName.givenName : '-',
                        'last_name': response.fullName ? response.fullName.familyName : '-',
                        'device_identifier': device_identifier,
                        device: Platform.OS
                    };
                    props.appleLogin({ values: details });
                }
            }
            // user is authenticated

        } catch (error) {
            if (appleAuth.Error.CANCELED === error.code) {
                console.log('apple-error-CANCELED', JSON.stringify(error));
            } else if (appleAuth.Error.FAILED === error.code) {
                console.log('apple-error-FAILED', error);
            } else if (appleAuth.Error.NOT_HANDLED === error.code) {
                console.log('apple-error-NOT_HANDLED', error);
            } else {
                console.log('apple-error', error);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Still having same issue in 2024
iOS 16 & iOS 17

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had this happen to me as well. Found the solution here https://github.com/invertase/react-native-apple-authentication/issues/162#issuecomment-723502035.

Basically, just use iOS 13 if you are on an emulator or iOS 14 on a real device.

Comment: i am using simulator with ios 15 but still not working, and keeps loading

Comment: @appdev It seems the issue still exists, just use ios 13 or a real device seems to be the only legitimate advice https://github.com/invertase/react-native-apple-authentication/issues/141#issuecomment-992497099.

Answer (score 0):

This also happened with me when I am trying to run the code on simulator, Try this on real device it will work.
Don't forgot to add **Sign In with Apple** for both release and debug App in **Signing & Capabilities** .For this you should have an ADP Account.

Thank you.